# Adding scraped list to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to return URLs for a list of Company names, then update the pandas dataframe to include the returned URLs.

I'm importing all dependencies and reading the .csv file:

```
import logging
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
from googlesearch import search

df = pd.read_csv('Building_Contractors_Stephen_V1.csv')

df.head()
```

[df.head() results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McGd7.png)

Then I'm defining a function that gets all URLs:

```
def get_urls(tag, n, language):
    urls = [url for url in search(tag, stop=n, lang=language)][:n]
    return urls
```

Then I'm testing that on one url:

```
test_return = get_urls(df.Hospital_Building_Contractors[0], 10, 'en') 
test_return
```

Which returns a list of URLs:

```
['https://www.turnerconstruction.com/',
 'http://www.turnerconstruction.com/careers',
 'http://www.turnerconstruction.com/office-network',
 'http://www.turnerconstruction.com/about-us',
 'http://www.turnerconstruction.com/turner-university',
 'http://www.turnerconstruction.com/careers/jobs',
 'http://www.turnerconstruction.com/about-us/where-we-work',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turner_Construction',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turner_Construction#History',
 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turner_Construction#Early_years']
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to iterate through all of the items in my lists, and add them to new columns in the dataframe.

Here's my code for that:

```
i = 0
num = len(df.Hospital_Building_Contractors)
while i < num:
    get_urls(df.Hospital_Building_Contractors[i], 1, 'en')
    df.insert(1, "URL", urls, allow_duplicates=True) 
    i += 1
```

Which returns this error:

> ---
>
> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>        17 while i < num:
>        18     get_urls(df.Hospital_Building_Contractors[i], 1, 'en')
>   ---> 19     df.insert(1, "URL", urls, allow_duplicates=True)
>        20     i += 1
>        21
>
> NameError: name 'urls' is not defined

I'm sure this is an easy problem to get around, but I'm stumped. 
I define 'urls' in the get_urls() function; so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Ideally, I'd have a solution that goes something like this:

```
a = 0
num = len(df.Hospital_Building_Contractors)
while a < num:
    get_urls(df.Hospital_Building_Contractors[a], 1, 'en')
    df.insert(1, "URL", urls, allow_duplicates=True) 
    a += 1


b = 0
num = len(df.University_Building_Contractors)
while b < num:
    get_urls(df.University_Building_Contractors[b], 1, 'en')
    df.insert(3, "URL", urls, allow_duplicates=True) 
    b += 1


c = 0
num = len(df.Hospital_Building_Contractors)
while c < num:
    get_urls(df.Hospital_Building_Contractors[c], 1, 'en')
    df.insert(5, "URL", urls, allow_duplicates=True) 
    c += 1
```

Which would iterate through each list, find URLs and add them to the dataframe.

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Comment: It's more likely that the problem is in my code, but I've detailed the issue in a comment on your answer below. Do you know how to fix it @jezrael?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom `lambda function` with filter for working only with strings:

```
from googlesearch import search

df = pd.read_csv('Building_Contractors_Stephen_V1.csv')
#print (df)


def get_urls(tag, n, language):
    urls = [url for url in search(tag, stop=n, lang=language)][:n]
    return urls

#for only one top1 value
f = lambda x: next(iter(get_urls(x, 1, 'en') if isinstance(x, str) else []), 'no value')
#for multiple top values, eg. top3
#f = lambda x: get_urls(x, 3, 'en') if isinstance(x, str) else []
df['a'] = df.Hospital_Building_Contractors.apply(f)
df['b'] = df.University_Building_Contractors.apply(f)
df['c'] = df.Military_Contractors.apply(f)
```

---

```
print (df.tail())
    Hospital_Building_Contractors University_Building_Contractors  \
104                Progressive AE                             NaN   
105           Hellas Construction                             NaN   
106               Wight & Company                             NaN   
107               PWI Engineering                             NaN   
108   Cordogan Clark & Associates                             NaN   

    Military_Contractors                                                a  \
104                  NaN  https://www.linkedin.com/company/progressive-ae   
105                  NaN               http://www.hellasconstruction.com/   
106                  NaN                         https://www.wightco.com/   
107                  NaN                            http://www.pwius.com/   
108                  NaN                    http://www.cordoganclark.com/   

            b         c  
104  no value  no value  
105  no value  no value  
106  no value  no value  
107  no value  no value  
108  no value  no value
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding new columns to a dataframe can be done by below.

```
df["new column name"] = urls #list
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, because urls list is for one value of `df.Hospital_Building_Contractors`